# View Engine dropdown not present while adding view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, view, razor

I am creating MVC music store application by reading the PDF, in that on page 22 there is a method shown to add view but when I right clicked on it I am getting the below screen:

**[Why I am not getting the View Engine Drop Down?]**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC 2 that's why you are not provided with this choice. You could use Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET MVC 3 installed. Only in ASP.NET MVC 3 projects you are provided with this choice.

Comment: Does it mean that I can not develop MVC Music Store on MVC 2 ? Please guide because this is my first asp.net MVC application.

Comment: @Chris, you can, but you will have to use the WebForms as view engine if you decide to use ASP.NET MVC 2. If you want to use Razor you need ASP.NET MVC 3.

Answer (score 2):

This is for MVC 3 only. It seems you are using MVC 2.

Comment: Will it be better to use Razor Engine or I can go ahead with the normal ASP.NET MVC engine?

Comment: With Razor your code is far more shorter, but more important are all other improvements from MVC 2 to MVC 3. I have projects with MVC 2 still in use, but new projects I start with MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Web Developer Express 2010 as per [section](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1):

1. File -> New Project

Installing the software

This will give you the IDE used in this tutorial and allow you to view the ASP.Net MVC3 tooling options such as presented in the dialogue box.